# Couchbase Error : client-side timout on get from couchbase

Tags: php, timeout, client-side, couchbase

Following is the error i am getting in app logs during CB connectivity. 
CouchbaseException: Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout in _CouchbaseBucket->get() (line 196 of [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php).
Note that this is during general browsing -- no load on Web server, nor CB server. Traffic load usually  2 or 3 user
Cpu load is 0.1 ,0.2 ....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I realized I need to open port 11210 on the server firewall.